# How to prove $\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{c+d}+\frac{c^3}{d+a}+\frac{d^3}{a+b}\geq\frac{1}{8}$ for $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R^+$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $a+b+c+d=1$. Prove that
$\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{c+d}+\frac{c^3}{d+a}+\frac{d^3}{a+b}\geq\frac{1}{8}.$

Please solve without Titu's or Holder's inequality.  I have not studied them yet. I have used AM-GM-HM, but it is becoming long and there is no progress.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably Harmonic Mean.

Comment: I would suggest you to write here your attempt, as I am not really interested to write everything down for you. :&

Comment: It follows immediately from CS inequality. Do you accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Use the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_-_n-dimensional_Euclidean_space)
  $$\underbrace{(a(b+c)+b(c+d)+c(d+a)+d(a+b))}_{=:G}\cdot \text{LHS} \ge (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$$
- Use the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality)
  $$G=(ab+bc+cd+da) +(2ac+2bd)\le 2\left(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2  \right) $$
- Use the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality a second time
  $$4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) \ge (a+b+c+d)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma.** For any positive real numbers $x$ and $y$ the inequality
$$
\frac{x^3}{y}\geq\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-y^2)
$$
holds.

*Proof.* Indeed, this is equivalent to $\frac{x^3}{y}+\frac{x^3}{y}+y^2\geq 3x^2$ which is an application of AM-GM inequality. $\square$

Next, multiply the LHS of the original inequality by 8 and apply the lemma as follows:
$$
\frac{(2a)^3}{b+c}+\frac{(2b)^3}{c+d}+\frac{(2c)^3}{d+a}+\frac{(2d)^3}{a+b}\geq\frac{1}{2}(12a^2-(b+c)^2)+\frac{1}{2}(12b^2-(c+d)^2)+\frac{1}{2}(12c^2-(d+a)^2)+\frac{1}{2}(12d^2-(a+b)^2),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
8\cdot\left(\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{c+d}+\frac{c^3}{d+a}+\frac{d^3}{a+b}\right)\geq 5(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)-(ab+bc+cd+da).
$$
Since
$$
5(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)-(ab+bc+cd+da)=4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)+\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2+(d-a)^2)\geq 4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2),
$$
and by AM-QM
$$
4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\geq (a+b+c+d)^2=1,
$$
we obtain the desired inequality
$$
8\cdot\left(\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{c+d}+\frac{c^3}{d+a}+\frac{d^3}{a+b}\right)\geq 1.
$$